# WPF, dialog boxes and forms

Tags: wpf, modal-dialog

I tried titling this, "A Very Stupid Question: WPF, dialog boxes and forms" but it wasn't allowed.

I am writing a WPF program in C#. I created this dialog box:
[image: A dialog box]

from within Visual Studio 2010 by selecting Add -> New Item -> Windows Form and then built the dialog box.

I CAN'T CATCH THE 'CANCEL'. Other than that, it works just fine.

Here's how I'm calling it:

```
 AdjustAlpha dlg = new AdjustAlpha();
 dlg.ShowDialog();
```

I've seen a lot of posts about the difference between WPF and Forms. I've tried using System.Windows.Forms, I've tried this:

```
 DialogResult result = new AdjustAlpha.ShowDialog();
 if (result == DialogResult.OK)
```

Throws lots of errors.

IS MY MISTAKE SIMPLY USING A WINDOWS FORM IN A WPF APP?

Comment: Dont use (dinosaur) winforms in WPF. By the way, UI is not Data. Therefore you don't actually ask the `DialogResult` from a UI element.

Comment: So you're saying just never try to mix winforms with WPF?

Comment: Not unless 100% needed, such as having some important 3rd party winforms component you cannot do in WPF or having some legacy thing you need to maintain. winforms is deprecated.

Comment: Okay, I'm redoing it in WPF/XAML. I just found the UI for designing the dialog box in winforms easier...

Comment: @zetar Because you linked to your dialog box image and that link is now gone, we can no longer see what you created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think mixing WinForms and WPF is becoming thing of the past. Yet, when you're confined by the project/company/TPS then you do, what you gotta do!

If you need to launch a WPF dialog from WinForms - look up how to use `ElementHost`. 
If you need to launch WinForms' dialog from WPF -create a class that implements the WinForms interface `IWin32Window` -- pass it's returned handle to WinForm's ShowDialog.

Comment: I'm still having trouble firing up a dialog box the proper WPF way. Is there a tutorial/example code around somewhere? I was getting a compiler error about ShowDialog() missing.

Comment: I discovered that this code:             if (dlg.ShowDialog().Equals(true)) will catch a Cancel/OK of a winform in WPF. Just sayin'

Comment: yep! ..or you could just do `if(dlg.ShowDialog())`, either way. sorry, just saw your comment - just woke up :)

Comment: if(dlg.ShowDialog()) is throwing a compiler error; the .Equals(true) is working for Cancel|Ok catching. It just really seems that creating a dialog box via XAML is really arduous as opposed to just clicking and dragging the buttons, sliders, listboxes, etc., that I need. And it also seems like it's easier to create the 'code behind', too. Winforms seems more like GUI creation systems on the old Mac, Atari ST, and Amiga. Using XAML seems like two steps back (just my $.02).

Comment: my bad, forgot the cast to bool , but your .Equals(true) is better as it is more readable. As far as other comment, well, you can drag and drop controls onto designer in VS. I just don't like it as it creates canvases, and bunch of weird stuff. XAML/WPF is much more powerful, but takes a learning curve at first. Don't get discouraged, once you're more familiar with it, you can crack out things way faster than WinForms. Good luck!